# Multiple :locals to a :partial being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I can't understand why I'm not able to use an additional local in my partial.

In my parent view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'content', :locals => { :post => post, :summary => true } %>
```

And in my partial:

```
<%= summary ? post_content(post, 220) : post_content(post) %>
```

Results in an error, where the variable summary can't found:

```
undefined method `summary?' for #<#<Class:0x007ff425e773b0>:0x007ff425e67a50>
```

Any ideas? I'm potentially being really stupid here...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to make the test expression more explicit, because the system is trying to find a method called summary? instead of using ? as ternary operator. Try changing it to:

```
<%= summary == true ? post_content(post, 220) : post_content(post) %>
```

Comment: This worked - thanks. Do you know why summary? or summary didn't work? I thought it would if it was a boolean... (noob here. :-) )

Comment: no, the true and false values do not have the ? operator on them.

Comment: Ah I know what I was thinking - booleans on an object. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please confirm that in your partial you indeed have `summary <space> ?` instead of `summary?`

Comment: A quick question. If there isn't a space doesn't that render the entire line of code incorrect? I mean, what exactly does it mean if he says `summary? post_content(post, 22) : post_content(post)`? Is the colon a valid operator in this case?

Comment: As Gonzalo Quero noted, "summary?" is the name of a function (e.g. myvar.is_a? String, where is_a? is the method name). In contrast, x ? y : z uses the ternary operator ? for a condition.

Comment: I tried both of <%= summary? ? post_content(post, 220) : post_content(post) %> and <%= summary ? post_content(post, 220) : post_content(post) %> but neither worked, but <%= summary == true ? post_content(post, 220) : post_content(post) %> did. I figured since summary was a boolean I could have just added a ? after it... I'm a noob. :-)

Comment: @blackbird07: He's passing a boolean in to that partial. true doesn't have the ? operator on it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully... it says that the method `summary?` can't be found, not `summary`.  Is it possible that your code doesn't included a space between summary and the question mark?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your model has a `summary` attribute or method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this--:summary is just the name that the partial will use to refer to the passed in parameter, true is that value of that parameter. nothing here ties it to the model, no? I'm asking, not asserting :)  Oh, and that's not my -1 up there